# How to handle 0 inflated data set?

Tags: r, scikit-learn, zero-inflation

How to handle a data set with high number of 0's. I am trying to predict automobile insurance claims of people. So many of them of are zeros. If the `claim == 1`  then `claim_amount = +ve integer`,  else `claim = 0`  and `claim_amount = 0`. There are high number of 0's(90%). How to develop a predictive model which can predict `claim` and `claim_amount`.

I tried `zeroinfl` method from CRAN `pscl` R package. The accuracy is very low. It should be done using Python or R. The data has around 22000 rows with 7 predictor variables and 2 target (`claim`, `claim_amount`) variables.

Comment: Split your prediction into two parts. One to predict if the claim is either zero or non-zero. Then, given that the claim is non-zero make a model to predict the claim amount.

Comment: I concur with @Hugh that a two-step strategy is probably most fruitful here. In terms of the `pscl` package this would correspond to a `hurdle` rather than a `zeroinfl` model. However, I'm not sure that a _count_ regression model is needed here. You could also fit a binary response model to `claim` and then a continuous response model to `log(claim_amount)` for `subset = claim == 1`. From classical (generalized) linear models to flexible machine learning techniques (as pointed out by @Bernhard) everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Zero inflation makes things difficult and we don't know what your expectations as to accuracy are. A simple way to let the zero inflation be handled by the algorithm would be a tree model (packages `rpart` oder `party`) or a lot of trees (package `randomForest` or `party`). 22000 rows are a lot, if 10% out of that are non-zero and there are 7 predictor variables this may even be enough for a sensible neural net.

More R packages on machine learning at https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=MachineLearning

In the following simulated example you can see, how well the different rules of generating zeros are modeled as well as the rule of number generation by a simple tree:

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

expl.data <- data.frame(A = sample(1:3, 22000, TRUE), B = sample(1:3, 22000, TRUE),
                        C = sample(1:10,22000, TRUE), D = runif(22000,0,100),
                        response = rep(NA, 22000))

rules <- function(A, B, C, D){
    if(D<20) return(0)
    if(D>80) return(0)
    if(C<3) return(0)
    if(A==1 & B==1) return(0)
    return(sample(1:20*A,1))
}

for (i in 1:nrow(expl.data)) # this can be done faster, this is most readable
    expl.data$response[i] <- rules(expl.data$A[i],
                                   expl.data$B[i],
                                   expl.data$C[i],
                                   expl.data$D[i])

prp(rpart(response ~ ., data=expl.data))
```

Which leads to
[image: graph of decision tree detecting zero rules etc.]